# Freeing the allocated memory of a zero-length array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct, free

I learned a new trick today, consisting of ending a struct with a zero-length array to allow that array to be dynamically sized as I need it. This is extremely handy and helps save a good amount of memory when I want to decide the amount of space my struct will eat up at run-time instead of compile time.

Using them works perfectly; then I remembered I need to free my allocated memory, so I just threw down a free(struct); in there, but to my dismay, that threw me an error:

```
    *** glibc detected *** ./program: free(): invalid next size (fast): <address>
    ======= Backtrace: =========
     <omitted>
    ======= Memory Map: ========
     <omitted>
```

Here's a simple example in poorly formatted code:

```
   struct Stuff {
     int size; // defines the amount of bytes the entire struct will take up
     char data[0];
   }

   ...

   // This gives me an int and a char[30].
   struct Stuff *ptr = (struct Stuff *) malloc(sizeof(struct Stuff) + 30); 

   ... 
   doStuff();
   ...

   free(ptr);
```

And I get the error at free(ptr);

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you doing with ptr in your doStuff method (the problem is probably there) ?

Comment: You're probably running off the end of `data` and corrupting something in the heap - the problem doesn't show up until you call `free()`, but the `free()` itself is not the problem.

Comment: Note also that the return of `malloc` should not be cast, and that fields with length zero are non standard and thus not portable. The standard way for the later is to omit the size for a terminating array field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `malloc()`/`free()` code is fine. To verify, comment out everything between the `malloc()` and the `free()`, and see if the problem goes away (I bet it does).

You almost certainly write past the end of the allocated memory somewhere (possibly in `doStuff()`). For example, if `doStuff()` uses `ptr->size` to determine the size of `ptr->data`, make sure `ptr->size` is initialized correctly.

Comment: Those both may seem like the likely problems. I tried freeing after the malloc and the rest of my code worked fine like it was never freed at all. I guess I'll need to do a big of bug hunting.

Comment: Hmm. I threw down a few memset()s on the problem structs and it seemed to clear up the problem. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: "seemed to clear up the problem" -> translation -> "masked the bugs in my code for now such that they will most likely come back to bite me later".

Comment: No, you're just assuming. The problem had to do with strings not null terminated properly, which is why it was running off the end. Memset fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove doStuff() for just leaving free(ptr) and retry. Do you have the same error ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code changes value of `ptr` somewhere.

Use:

```
struct Stuff * const ptr = ...
```

Instead of:

```
struct Stuff * ptr = ...
```

To detect this kind of problems at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably whatever you are doing in `doStuff()` is using more than the 30 extra bytes you've allocated beyond the struct header. Make sure you are correctly calculating the amount of space you need.